# How to target WebGL compatibility solely in terms of hardware performance

Tags: javascript, optimization, canvas, three.js, webgl

Recently I've been working with Three.js in order to render 3D scenes in WebGL. As a fallback, I've also maintained versions using Three's CanvasRenderer that, while they do not have as many polygons, lighting techniques, or effects, can still run in browsers that do not have WebGL capability (and can also run in Safari if the user refuses to enable WebGL themselves).

However, today I realized that compatibility is not merely a question of whether or not the user's browser supports WebGL, but also whether the user's hardware is even rigorous enough to perfectly render WebGL in the first place (i.e. run at 60 fps). While there is a lot of data out there illustrating what percentage of the population uses which web browser, I had trouble finding distributions of users who are running computers more than capable of running WebGL.

What exactly is the percentage of the population that -- assuming they are using a WebGL capable web browser -- can run your average WebGL page at 60 fps? And if it is a large amount of the population who struggle with rendering in WebGL, what would be the best way to detect such shortcomings in hardware? A javascript solution would be ideal since we are already working with Three in that language.

It is very possible that I may be misunderstanding the situation as this does not seem to be a widely discussed issue in the world of WebGL development. If such is the case please let me know so I may better understand how to work with Three in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you work with three.js you can query for extensions:

```
gl = renderer.getContext();
exts = gl.getSupportedExtensions();
```

so if you don't get something like float textures, you get some idea of what you're working with. WebGL is built around the lowest common denominator.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue professionally working with Android - we had a 3D intensive app prior to release of a hardware accelerated Android OS, it ran smoothly on some phones and horribly on others.  This issue crops up on any open platform like Android or Windows.  iPhones/iPad have a very explicit hardware set, but on the PC you will be getting a range of video cards.

If you use Cg/HLSL shaders you compile to a specific hardware profile which describes the lower bound of the vertex, geometry and pixel shaders.  However I'm guessing you're using GLSL shaders and compiling at runtime?   GLSL does not target hardware profiles and will simply fail to compile the shader if the hardware in incapable of running it.

Of course, this only gives you an idea of whether the program can execute, not *how well* it can execute.  A shader can compile just fine and run at 5fps.

I was worried about users seeing a bad graphics experience so for our app on the first run I rendered a model to an offscreen target for a brief time and took an average FPS, then disabled the 3D section if the score was too low.  You know what?  **THE USERS HATED IT.** Plenty of them had 3D-capable phones and felt cheated that they couldn't see the 3D sections that were in the screenshots.  I pushed an update to remove the check, so now if you have bad hardware you'll see the 3D scene running slowly.  And we actually had fewer complaints with that experience, even though I hated how inelegant it seemed.

On the positive side, both OS X and Windows (since Vista) support hardware accelerated compositing in the OS (GL/D3D renders all your windows to the screen now).  This has pushed most every PC vendor to include 3D acceleration in their computers.  So I think it's a safe bet to assume people have a 3D card - whether they have WebGL will be more of a limiting factor.  The variety of hardware and drivers also gives you wacky rendering bugs on one machine that appear nowhere else - PC game developers test on a range of cards prior to release in an attempt to mitigate that issue.  But these wacky bugs are going to be a tiny fraction of your users at most and are often trivial, so it isn't worth worrying about unless users are complaining.

If you're still worried about performance, the standard solution on the PC is to allow the user to adjust the graphics settings to reduce the complexity of the pixel shader / number of triangles on the screen / etc.  Make sure to look at real-world data about what hardware most of your customers own and use that range for targeting and testing.

Anyway, there's a real-world anecdote, HTH.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed vignette. I certainly didn't think so at first, but what you mentioned about users being oblivious to slow performance (as long as the graphics are faithful) makes sense psychologically. After all, the user is probably already aware of their hardware's limitations and isn't going to blame the developer for being unable to change that. Part of the issue then is not only finding data about hardware users own but getting a benchmark for the WebGL scene so that that data can be meaningful.

Comment: I'm not sure what your application is but in the past for games I've recorded user input while I was playing it for a few minutes and used that to play it back while validating the FPS did not dip below 60.  This is at least automated.

In interpreted languages like JS, if you don't use object pools the garbage collection can cause sporadic performance drops so validating that you don't fall below a threshold is a good idea.  Most JS implementations have been optimized to hell and back at this point though so don't fall into the premature optimization trap.

Comment: If you get to the point where you're wondering what is causing a graphical hiccup, IMO the gold standard for video card optimization are the NVIDIA performance tools (formerly PerfHUD), which require an NVIDIA card, a standalone exe and Visual Studio at the moment.  Making a JS runtime into a standalone exe isn't very difficult so I suspect someone's done it by now.